# Check the status of a batch file. If its not running, it should be started

Tags: batch-file

When I check the status of my batch file by running the command

```
First.bat status
```

if it's active returns `java.exe`
or else returns `No tasks are running which match the specified criteria`.

I want to create a new batch file to check the status of the `First.bat` file and should run the command `First.bat start` if the status returns `no tasks are running`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your intentions with us. What is your question?

Comment: `first.bat status | find /i "No tasks are running" && first.bat start`